# Ruby get mime-type based on extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mime-types

How can I get a mime-type based on a file extension?

Comment: This question is unclear. Are you asking for a method called `get_mime_type`? And are you saying you want the mime type to come from a list of known file extensions - mime types?

Comment: @Beartech I made that method up to give an example. I changed my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using Rails you can get the mime-type with [Rack::Mime](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/mime.rb#L16).

```
mime_type = Rack::Mime.mime_type(extension)
```

Comment: @Cort3z no worries. [You can find the module and method here](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/mime.rb#L16). I will update the answer.