# Why file being downloaded instead of opening ? ( Ruby, WEBrick )

Tags: ruby, header, mime-types, webrick

I have this `if` statement:

```
if File.exist?(BASE_PATH + request.path)
    extention = strip_arbitrary(extention, ".")
    response.content_type = MIME::Types.type_for('css')
    response.body = File.read(BASE_PATH + request.path)
else
    response.body = BASE_PATH + request.path
end
```

So when the top ones true it just gives me the save as window for the css file. What can I do with this? I want a proper css file to appear in my browser.

I asked [the previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25684492/how-to-determine-mime-type-by-the-file-extension-ruby) if anyone is wondering what `MIME::Types.type_for` is.

### Also getting red `text/css`

[image: On Chrome]